# How to make style in Geoserver different for last X hours?

Tags: geoserver, style, time

When I want to set style for points (for example) representing events I would like to achieve that points created in last hour have different color than others. Is there any easy way to achieve it?

I know that there is a possible solution to run cron every minute and set status (example: last_hour: true / false) regarding time and than use this as an attribute to style data. But this solution is so ugly.

I have been looking to do something like this (using ECQL):

```
CREATED_AT >= TIMESTAMP - '1 hour'
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Which geoserver endpoint are you using to retrieve the data? (WFS, WMS etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past I have made use of the [GeoServer variable substitution](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html) mechanism to pass in the current date/time to use in an SLD, It may be easiest to calculate the datetime 1hr ago and pass that in. You could then use a temporal filter to set your style. Something like the following untested SLD might work:

```
    <ogc:After>
    <ogc:PropertyName>time_col</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Function name="env">
        <ogc:Literal>date</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>2016-11-16T12:00:00</ogc:Literal>
     </ogc:Function>
     </ogc:After>
```

Comment: Thanks! This one will probably do it. I thought there is easier way to get current timestamp in style.

Answer (score 1):

the most natural way would be to create some new [filter functions](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html) to do date based math. That of course requires development.

If your data is in a spatial database there is however a more immediate way to achieve your goal, create a sql view in which you'll add a dynamically computed attribute, a boolean flag, which is up only if the data is recent enough, and then use such flag for styling.